# RROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path error when uploading ipa file

Tags: html, ios, xml, cordova, phonegap-build

I have developed an app in HTML and JavaScript and when I come to upload the .ipa file to Application loader I get the following errors:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'icon.png'"
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '57x57' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions < 7.0."
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '72x72' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions < 7.0."
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the <basename> portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5' and the 'iOS App Programming Guide' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12'."
```

The thing is all the images are there to the correct size and referenced within the config.xml file. I have looked over a large number of sites and have found no fixes. My config.xml relating to the iOS images is as follows:

```
<icon src="icon.png"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using PhoneGap Build, the paths used on *config.xml* are relative to `www/` so you should remove the *www/* from the start of your *icon src* paths.

The [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html) claims that

> src: (required) specifies the location of the image file, relative to your www directory

In my opinion, it would be nice of PGB to inform user that it didn't find the images..

Comment: Awesome, it's weird that all paths are generated with www/ when using the CLI to generate the configs.